# What's the syntax for using Some as function?

Tags: rust, syntax

```
self.0.iter().map(Some)
```

https://github.com/zcash/halo2/blob/main/halo2_proofs/src/circuit/floor_planner/v1/strategy.rs#L71

I tried to google some keywords, but didn't find any result.

Comment: What question do you have?

Comment: Why `Some` can be used as function? It's an enum.

Comment: It's just a syntax sugar. Even `struct` may be used as a function:
`struct A(u32); [1u32, 2u32].iter().copied().map(A); // iterator of A`

Comment: Here is another example where `Some` is used "like a function": `Some(dividend / divisor)` 
[ https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/option.html ]

Comment: @Dmitry there must be somewhere that implements `FnMut` for `struct A` and `Some`, right? Is there any spec for this kind of behavior?

Comment: The compiler takes the tuple struct declaration`struct A(u8)` both as the definition of a type `A` and a function `A` (there is [no](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html#tuple-struct-expression) difference to any other function). This function has it's own unique [item type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html), which can be coerced to a type `fn(…) -> …`, which then impls(?) `FnMut` and friends.

Comment: The term for that is "type constructor", but I am not aware of official documentation calling it so. This is how it is called in the compiler, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion, so let's clarify things. `Some` is not an enum (as you said in a comment), it's *part* of an enum, that is, the `Option<T>` type was defined as

```rust
enum Option<T> {
    Some(T),
    None,
}
```

Here, `Some(T)` is called a variant of this enum. However, for convenience, the compiler will produce a function with the same name, with the same signature, that simply produces that variant. That is, `Some: fn(T) -> Option<T>`. Similarly, the `None` variant produces a constant of the same name.

Comment: Is there any spec mentioning this?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie Unfortunately, the Rust reference is not complete. For the constant with the same name, [it is documented there](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/structs.html), but for the function part, you can [check that it's the case on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2d80a1f1ad79a9d6bfc96c5644292a01). Note that `fn(i32) -> A` is a function pointer type, which means it's a proper function, not just something that can be called (like a closure).